# Symfony2/Doctrine - How to select a single tag from a blog.tags property

Tags: symfony, tags, doctrine, twig

How can I select a single tag from blog.tags? I am trying to link a single tag from blog.tags property. Right now when I hover over a single tag I get see the group of tags instead just the single one.

Tags

[image: tags for the post]

Group of tags when hovering over one tag:

[image: group tags instead of just one]

I am using a for loop for all blogs and it's properties in the twig file. I need to be able to select on each tag in the blog.tags field to link it, how do I set this up?

**twig file**

```
{% for blog in pagination %}
 {% for tag in blog.tagsArray %}
   <p>Tags: <span class="highlight"><a href="{{ path('AcmeDemoBundle_tag', { 'tag': tag }) }}">{{ tag }}</a></span></p><br><br>
 {% endfor %}    
{% endfor %}
```

**entity**

```
/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="tags", type="text")
 */
private $tags;

/**
 * Set tags
 *
 * @param string $tags
 * @return Blog
 */
public function setTags($tags)
{
    $this->tags = $tags;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get tags
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getTags()
{
    return $this->tags;
}
```

**controller**

```
public function indexAction($tag = null)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $blogs = $em->getRepository('LSHealthFitnessBundle:Blog')
        ->getBlogs();

    $tags = $em->getRepository('LSHealthFitnessBundle:Blog')
        ->getTags();

    $postTags = $em->getRepository('LSHealthFitnessBundle:Blog')
        ->getPostsByTags($tag);

    $paginator  = $this->get('knp_paginator');
    $pagination = $paginator->paginate(
        $blogs,
        $this->get('request')->query->get('page', 1)/*page number*/,
        5/*limit per page*/
    );

    return array(
        'blogs'      => $blogs,
        'tags'       => $tags,
        'postTags'   => $postTags,
        'pagination' => $pagination,
    );
}
```

List format: (per answer response)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write second for loop in you twig tamplate, like this:

```
{% for blog in pagination %}
    {% for tag in blog.tagsArray %}
        <a href="{{ path('AcmeDemoBundle_tag', { 'tag': tag }) }}">{{ tag }}</a>&nbsp;
    {% endfor %}
    <br/>
{% endfor %}
```

This will create a list of tag for each blog (each in separate line)

**[EDIT]:**

Add something like this to your Blog entity:

```
public function getTagsArray()
{
    return explode(',' ,$this->tags);
}
```

This will convert tags string to array (delimited by comma). Then you can get tags array by calling `blog.tagsArray` in twig. I have updated code above.

Comment: Hmmm trying this made my entire comment line disappear?

Comment: I thought there is ManyToMany a relation between Blogs and Tags.  Answer updated.

Comment: Ok the comments are back but it's listed in a list format vertically (tags: ex1, next line, tags: ex2 etc.) not like it was in the original one line. tags: ex1, ex2, ex 3 etc.

Comment: Any way to change this so it's not on their separate lines? So it's just Tags: Ex1, Ex2, Ex3 etc. But it's still selectable?

Comment: Did you add second loop to your twig? Can you update your template code in question?

Comment: You have your tag link wraped in <p> - witch breaks the line - and two </br> after each tag - thats why all your tags are in separate lines

Comment: You should change your HTML. See my answer (twig).

Comment: You sir, are a scholar and a gentleman, thank you so much for taking the time to show me how this works. I know the setup isn't ideal but I am still in the learning phases. Thank you pazulx.

Comment: Curious in you solution, question how does the getTagsArray() work, I mean how does it convert the tags string to an array? I noticed when I remove the explode, the comments no longer, how does this work?

Comment: explode is an standard php function - for converting strings to arrays - more info [here](http://pl1.php.net/explode)

Comment: Ok. So when removing explode why did the comments disappear? If removing explode then the tags are one string, correct? What would cause it not appear --- when we originally used blog.tags instead of blog.tagsArray?

Comment: when you remove explode and return string then it can't be iterated in `for` loop and I think thats why it is not visible (maybe check server logs for some errors that are not displayed).

Comment: I think I understand, because you can't loop through a single string, correct? Originally blog.tags was a tag string, right?